# Creating an SQL table from a select statement with condition

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with columns Name and Salary. I was able to return only the rows that have a Salary greater than 50000 (7 rows returned).

I now want to make a table that has only 1 column called Count, and a single entry, 7. I can obviously hard code a new table with these features. However, I am wondering if it is possible to achieve my desired end result without having to make a new table?

My intuition is that GROUP BY might be helpful but I haven't been able to figure anything out. 
So far what I have is:

`SELECT salary FROM table1 WHERE salary > 50000`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `COUNT` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE salary > 50000
```

Comment: Thanks, something quick and easy like this is what I was looking for.